# Select menu extends beyond its physical shape

Tags: css, html

I'm a beginner to HTML and CSS. I'm using jquery mobile, and jquery ui to build a page. I have added a select menu and two images as buttons next to it. I have set a border width of 1px to see the layout. As it is seen in the picture below select menu border is extended and covers the images so I can't click on them.

[select menu border covers image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlOtv.png)

This is the html

```
<div id="container" >
  <img src="styles/add_button.png" id="addButton" class="imgButton"> 
  <img src="styles/remove_button.png" id="removeButton" class="imgButton">
  <form>          
    <select name="select-native-1" id="selectMenu">
  </select>                 
  </form>
</div>
```

this is the CSS

```
.imgButton{
    float : right;
    margin: 0em .2em;
}

#container{
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin:0em 1em 1em 1em;
}

#selectMenu{
    float: right;
}
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I find tables to be the easiest way to properly align things. Try this...

```
<table><tr> 
<td><select name="select-native-1" id="selectMenu">    </select></td> 
<td><img src="styles/add_button.png" id="addButton"    class="imgButton"> </td> 
<td><img src="styles/remove_button.png"    id="removeButton" class="imgButton"></td> 
</tr> </table>
```

And then add widths to the td elements to give it the look you want.